# Will server bandwidth affect MySQL performance?

Tags: mysql

I'm performing query testing using Heidisql and here is the result

[image]

As you can see from image query perform 0.1sec but network took 30+ sec to return data. My server bandwidth configuration is 5mbps.If I increase the server bandwidth will improve server response time?

Comment: If the network is the bottleneck, then increasing bandwidth should help.

Comment: It's not the MySQL performance directly which is affected. If you run that query locally on the server itself, not from remote, then the result should be quicker available. That's why applications often run on the same server as the MySQL service.

Comment: It takes a long time to shovel 974K rows across any network, even locally!  What are ou going to do with that many rows?